# Filter specific output of bash -x

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to filter specific output produced when executing bash -x command. Here is the code I have :

```
            touch ./log/time_$now_time.txt
            touch ./log/session_$now_time.log
            case $multinode in
                            true)whiptail --title "Multinode system" --msgbox "Multinode system found! Redirecting to the Multinode Menu... " 10 60
                                    cd multinode
                                    script -q -t 2> ../log/time_$now_time.txt -c "bash -x ./menu.sh" -f ../log/session_$now_time.log ;;
                            false)whiptail --title "Singlenode system" --msgbox "Singlenode system found!Redirecting to the Singlenode Menu..." 10 60
                                    cd singlenode
                                    script -q -t 2> ../log/time_$now_time.txt -c "bash -x ./menu.sh" -f ../log/session_$now_time.log;;
                            *)
                                    echo "Invalid option. Quitting"
                                    break ;;
            esac
```

Is there a way to log all +++ output produced by bash -x , but not to display it ? 
If I redirect all the output to /dev/null I'm losing the whiptail view as well, however I dont want to lose the bash -x outputs , but just not to be displayed .

Here is what I see when I start my script :

```
+++ date +%d_%m_%Y
++ now=11_09_2017
+ true
++ whiptail --title 'Multinode Main Menu' --menu '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'...
+ case $OPTION in
+ echo 'Bye !'
Bye !
#
```

How can I hide all the +++ lines, but log them in the session log file ?

Answer (score 0):

The special variable `BASH_XTRACEFD` allows to use another file descriptor than 2.
[reference][1]
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

```
exec 5> commands.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD=5
set -x
```

Or to integrate in provided script

```
... "BASH_XTRACEFD=5 bash -x ./menu.sh 5> commands.log" ...
```

also, error output (`2>`) is redirected in the same file provided by `script` `-f` option , is it wanted ?

To have errors and commands of menu.sh in a separate file and not `gnu script` messages

```
... "bash -x ./menu.sh 2> err_and_commands.log" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just tried it , it doesnt seem to hide the +++ outputs , neither redirect them to commands.txt . File is empty . The -f option is specifyng the session log for later replay of the session . Yes , I need it . What I want to have basicly is the session log from the script logging command and a text file containing the commands that were executed by the shell scripts.

Comment: yes , basically I want everything redirected to the commands.log , also errors.

Comment: in this case just change the file after `2>`, and keep the default xtrace file descriptor

Comment: oh maybe i understood you want only the error output of menu.sh script and not the error of script, i update my answer

Comment: thanks , but the above one "bash -x ./menu.sh 2> err_and_commands.log" is also hiding/redirecting the whiptail view along with the other messages . menu.sh contains whiptail menu window .

Comment: in fact i didn't konw really what script is used for but from manual : `It  is  not  recommended to run script in non-interactive shells.  The inner shell of script is always interactive, and this could lead to unexpected results.`, it seems maybe you're not using it correctly